# Как правильно начать цепочку промисов?

Tags: javascript, frontend, promise

Имеется 2 обычных функции , `f1()` и `f2()`. Вторая должна выполнится после окончания выполнения первой . Правильным ли является решение снизу или есть более короткий путь решения без `Promise.resolve()`?

```js
Promise.resolve()
.then(f1)
.then(f2)
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: что значит _2 обычных функции_?

Comment: Если функции выполняются синхронно (вполне себе _обычные_), то короткий путь: `f1(); f2();`

Answer (score 1):

Если есть вопрос по порядку выполнения, полагаю, что "обычные функции" - асинхронные, т.е., в том числе, возвращающие promise.
В этом случае предложенный вариант самый короткий и кросс-браузерный.
Есть еще такой.

```js
function f1() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('f1 done');
      resolve('f1');
    }, 2000);

  });
}

function f2() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
     console.log('f2 done');
     resolve('f2')
    }, 1000);
  });
}


(async () => {
  await f1();
  await f2();
})()
```

Comment: если возвращает Promise, То самый короткий будет `f1().then(f2)`

Comment: Согласен. Усложнил. Promise.resolve предполагает наличие данных, но их можно также в качестве аргумента первой функции задать. Я так думаю.

Comment: @Grundy если написать `f1().then(f2)`, то функция f1 может выкинуть обычное исключение вместо возврата rejected-промиза. В итоге обработку исключений придется дублировать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, все зависит от содержимого функций

Comment: Скажем так : первая функция синхронная , выполняет загрузку данных в стейт из локального хранилища (state.data=localStorage.getItem(“data”);). Этот процесс может быть длинным и блокировать поток , правильно ? Нужно что бы 2 операция выполнилась только после окончания первой

Comment: @АртёмНегода значит просто `f1(); f2();`